# Get new selection in a GtkTreeView during the signal

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

I want to detect whenever the selection of my `gtk.TreeView` changes and, when it does, to call a function w/ this information. The only way I've found to do it so far is to attach to all these signals:

```
...
    self.sitterView.connect("cursor-changed", self.selectionChanged)
    self.sitterView.connect("unselect-all", self.selectionChanged)
    self.sitterView.connect("toggle-cursor-row", self.selectionChanged)
    self.sitterView.connect("select-all", self.selectionChanged)    
...
def selectionChanged(self, treeview):
    foo(self.sitterView.get_selection().get_selected())
```

However, it seems like the selection I get from the callback is "delayed". That is, it shows the selection after the previous callback had completed. For example, if I constantly CTRL+click on a row, when the row goes from deselected to selected, foo is given no selection, and when the row goes from selected to deselected, it is given a selection. If I call `get_selection().get_selected()` a second later, though, I get the right selection. Any idea how to deal w/ this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what `toggle-cursor-row` does (the documentation is frustratingly empty), but I think that's the wrong signal to handle.

Instead, you should connect to the GtkTreeSelection [`changed`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkTreeSelection.html#GtkTreeSelection-changed) signal. It should take care of all selection change events, so you don't need to connect to the other signals either.

Comment: oh awesome! i didn't realize that the selection object wouldn't change, and that it had signals of its own. i think that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to connect this signal from Glade?

Comment: umpirsky: Not that I can tell. There is a Tree Selection object in Glade (under Tree Model) but I can't find a way to use it in a treeview.